# Сбой apache при подключении php

Tags: apache, php

Всем привет, почему когда добавляю строки:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php phtml php
LoadModule php5_module c:/php/php5.dll
```

У меня сразу происходит сбой при запуске Apache
и ещё из какого именно файла мне делать файл `php.ini`
из `php.ini-devilopmen` или `php.ini-production`?
и стоит ли `php5.dll` переименовывать в `php5apache2.dll`

Comment: если происходит сбой - скопируйте строку с ошибкой.

Какой из файлов использовать для основы? все очень просто. Если Вам для разработки - php.ini-devilopmen (я думаю, в названии файла ошибка). Если на рабочий боевой сервер, тогда php.ini-production. 

А переименовывать файл... а зачем? от переименования файла функциональность обычно не меняется.

Comment: вообще apache отказывается работать из за этих только строк, как только строки удаляю, apache сразу запускаеться

Comment: Что в логах? Если запустить апач вручную - что выводится на консоль? И, наконец: почему каждый раз нужно вытаскивать простейшую информацию из топикстартеров клещами? :-)

Answer (score 1):

У Вас скорее всего бинарники php и apache не совместимы, а в логах предложение о том, что не удается загрузить dll-библиотеку и много-много непонятных hex-кодов. Если это так, то скачайте apache, который, прежде всего, подходит под Вашу операционку. Apache под Windows есть тут: http://www.apachelounge.com/download/ .  Если кратко, то правила выбора нужной версии такие:

1. Если XP - то, обязательно, VC9. На семерке выбирайте VC11.
2. Битность бинарников и версия VC (Visual C++), используемая при их компиляции, у php и apache должны совпадать.

Файл делайте из php.ini-development. Production - используется на серверах с уже законченным приложением.

В apache нужно прописать путь до php.ini. Или скопируйте файл в директорию windows. Но как только я узнал, что можно просто прописать путь, всегда с тех пор делаю так.

Comment: а как именно прописать путь до php.ini?

Comment: Через директиву PHPIniDir:

    <IfModule php5_module>
        PHPIniDir "c:/php"
    </IfModule>